# Android Studio why i have to reinstall the sdk every time?

Tags: java, android, sdk, settings

I have a problem in my school, we had install Android Studio v. 1.5 two years ago and our problem is that every time we started AS we had to reinstall SDK also if he was the same person who accessed.
Now we are installing AS 3.1 but we are not sure that it's work correctly.
Someone who had the same problem?
Sorry for English ;D

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the latest version of Android studio. While installing, in the choose component page make sure to check the Android SDK component like in below image.
hope it helps you

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGbO3.png)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to locate the previous SDK installation and set its path in the android studio  preferences -> System Settings -> Android SDK